# How to access href of a class?

Tags: css, href, attr

first have to say that I have no idea of CSS. I am googling around and trying to customize my Squarespace webpage, reading comments, testing... Now I'm trying to make my blog more print-friendly. I inspected the entire page, looked for id's, classes, etc and then used

```
<style media="print" type="text/css">     /*Hide elements you don't want to print*/ 
#header, #footer, #preFooter, #rightSidebar, #sidecarNav, #contentinfo, #yui3-css-stamp, #_atssh, #service-icons-0, #rw_lso_flash, #at4-thankyou, .meta-above-title, .meta-below-title, .p-comment, .sqs-block-markdown, .rw-ui-squarespace-container, .entry-footer, .pagination
{display:none;}  </style>
```

to remove whatever I don't want to be printed. However, there is one element which I don't know how to add to the list. It is basically the url address of my post title. I tried `$(".entry-title.p-name").attr("href")` but it didn't work. This is the code of one arbitrary post title on my blog:

```
  <h1 data-content-field="title" class="entry-title p-name">
 <a href="/updates/2016/4/7/fathers-sons-and-fishes" class="u-url" rel="bookmark">
Fathers, Sons and Fishes</a></h1>
```

I hope you can help me with this one.
Sincerely, Artur

Comment: You can just use the class of <a> in jquery. `$('u-url').attr('href')`.

Comment: When I add this to the list however and try to print the page, it becomes a mess (all the other things which were supposed to be removed appear). I'm not sure what is the issue...

Comment: Can you post your javascript as well?

Comment: What is javascript? I just started learning these things today, sorry for the stupid questions:)

Comment: This code `$(".entry-title.p-name").attr("href")` you tried to add, where did you add this?

Comment: Inbetween the other id's and classes - #header, #footer, ... , $(".entry-title.p-name").attr("href"), etc.

Comment: That seems to be the problem then. You are supposed to add that betweeb `<script></script>` tags. These tags allow the webpage to execute javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108680/discussion-between-artur-kirkoryan-and-iwumbo).

Comment: There's no need for javascript here.

Comment: Still not working guys, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
.entry-title.p-name > a { display: none; }
```

Should work.

It sets any anchor inside a div with `class="entry-title p-name"` to non-visible. The `>` item indicates "child of". So, it translates to `.entry-title.p-name 'children' a`

Barring this, you can add a class to these specific anchors to hide that class.

What you have posted you tried (`$(".entry-title.p-name").attr("href")`) is a **javascript** or **jquery** selector. It is not CSS. You don't need javascript/jquery for this. If can be done with CSS.

Comment: The problem is that this hides the blog post title as well (not just the url). Can we keep one and remove the other?

Comment: Is the blog post title also an anchor? If it is,you can try something like `.entry-title.p-name > a:last-of-type {display: none;}` **Really** need to see complete HTML though to really be helpful. This is all just guessing since clearly, based on your comment above, you haven't shared correct HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it is still not working... Where can I find this HTML?

Comment: ermm.... the HTML is *your markup*. Now you aren't making sense. What HTML are you expecting to "find"?

Comment: I have no idea how to use HTML/JAVA so eventually just removed the title and left the main text. Thanks for the help though, appreciate it.